# setCellValue(String value) throws java: cannot access java.time.LocalDate class file for java.time.LocalDate not found

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-11

I am trying to write a map<String, String> into an xlsx file using Apache POI.

```
int rowIndex = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
    Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0,  CellType.STRING);
    cell0.setCellValue(e.getKey());
    Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1,  CellType.STRING);
    cell1.setCellValue(e.getValue());
}
```

Having tried with Apache POI - v5.0.0 and v4.1.2, I am getting the same error:

> java: cannot access java.time.LocalDate
> class file for java.time.LocalDate not found

Comment: Are you using an unusual Java runtime? - your label says java-11 but java.time.LocalDate has been part of core Java since Java 8

Comment: Thanks @PJ Fanning. Maven compiler source and target were set to java v1.7. Seems like I was looking in the wrong direction. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

me too. i'm using idea,but the java compiler default in use is 1.7,so change it above 1.7,everything is ok

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).